# curl multi handle and cookies

Tags: php, curl

My code creates basic curl handle by `curl_init` and then sets some options. Then I am using this handle to log-in on some website. I works fine. When I am logged in I would like to access some resources on website that are available only for logged int users. But I want to do it simultanously using `curl_multi`.

So after logging in I use `curl_copy_handle` on the handle that I used to log in, I set up new URL for copied handle and add copied handle to curl multi handle.

Then I execute curl multi handle - It works without errors but it can't access member resources - it seems that curl_copy_handle() doesn't copy cookies?

How can I copy all cookies (set up during login) along with curl_copy_handle?

I am not pasteing code here because it works ok - I just need method to share cookies with multiple handles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

presuming that you have the correct cookie value, going from the documentation you can use curl_setopt with the CURLOPT_COOKIE value to set them for the request.

```
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "Name=Value");
```

[curl-setopt function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

So just call that on your handle before performing curl_copy_handle. (there's also CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to specify a physical cookie you saved.

I haven't ever used this myself though.

Answer (score 0):

Play with CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE inside your curl_copy_handle.